# Nuxt with Vuetify theme styles in head section

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm using `Vuetify` with `Nuxt.js` and I have chunked out my css files so that when I use npm run generate all my my styles aren't included in every page on my site. To acheive doing this, iv'e added....

```
 build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    splitChunks: {
       layouts: true
    }
}
```

However my `vuetify-theme-stylesheet` theme files are still being included on every page. How can I get my `vuetify-theme-stylesheet`files to be chunked like the rest of my CSS?

```
<style data-n-head="vuetify" type="text/css" id="vuetify-theme-stylesheet" nonce="undefined">.v-application a{color:#0769ba}.v-application .primary{background-color:#0769ba!important;border-color:#0769ba!important}.v-application .primary--text{color:#0769ba!important;caret-color:#0769ba!important}
```

Comment: Although there is no accepted answer for the time being, your question on itself solved my issue, i.e. the `extractCSS` option alone. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After you've extracted the contents of the `<style>` tag in the head to a css file, you need to adjust certain fields in your config.

In your `nuxt.config.js`, you need to set the theme to disabled and link the extracted vuetify css.

```js
export default {
    css: [
        './assets/vuetify.css' // the extracted vuetify css
    ],
    vuetify: {
        theme: {
            disable: true
        }
    }
}
```

Now keep in mind that if you want to modify your theme (colours, etc.), you'll need to make these changes in your new css file (`assets/vuetify.css`)

This will also avoid a slight delay in the full css load, prevent a switch in display

Comment: Is it manual way?